# Как сократить запись сравнения значений в списках

Tags: python

Есть два списка. Задача получить True если первый элемент первого списка меньше первого элемента второго списка и так дале, для всех элементов обоих списков.

```
 if list1[0] < list2[0] \
            and list1[1] < list2[1] \
            and list1[2] < list2[2]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Понимаю что решение в лямбде, но где-то ошибка синтаксиса у меня и самостоятельно написать не смог.

Comment: Решение не столько в лямбде (которой у вас нет и она не нужна), сколько в цикле (которого тоже нет, но он нужен)

Comment: [True if x1 < x2 else False for x1, x2 in zip(lst1, lst2)]

Comment: @СергейШ `True` и `False` тут избыточны, также как и `if` с `else` ;)

Comment: `print(all(a < b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)))`

Comment: @АлексейР я новичок самоучка, такого синтаксиса еще даже не встречал! Спасибо, что приняли участие в вопросе!

Comment: @CrazyElf шикарное решение! Не могу найти кнопку как пометить Ваш ответ(((

Comment: А это комментарий, а не ответ. Просто это наверняка дубль, но мне лень выяснять. Ладно, добавлю как ответ на всякий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
print(all(a < b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)))
```

То есть, читаем код буквально: "Вернуть истину, если для всех пар `a` и `b` выполняется условие `a < b`, где `a` и `b` - взятые попарно (параллельно) элементы из `list1` и `list2` [, иначе вернуть ложь].

Answer (score 0):

Не очень красиво, только для 3-элементныцх списков, но для начинающих более понятно:

```
def compare(list1, list2):
    for i in 0, 1, 2:
        if not list1[i] < list2[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Когда встретится хотя одна пара элементов не удовлетворяет требованию *первый < второй*, ход функции прекращается и она возвращает `False`.
Иначе команда `return False` не исполнится, значит, исполнится команда `return True`.

---

*Примечание:*

Вместо `for i in 0, 1, 2:` возможно применить `for i in range(len(list1)):`, чтобы код работал для списков любой (но одинаковой) длины.

---

*Тест:*

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 3]

compare(list1, list2)        # False
```

Comment: Что-то подобно у меня было в коде, я хотел избавиться от длинных и многострочных записей, первый вариант с этой задачей справился на ура!